# Sharepoint 2010 API for adding new Trusted Identity Token Issuer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, saml, federated-identity

Does anyone know a Sharepoint 2010 API for adding a new trusted identity token issuer (aka identity provider)?

I can do this using the PS cmdlet New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer, but I need to do it from C# code.

Answer (score 0):

If you open Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell.dll in .Net Reflector it reveals that the implementation if SPCmdletNewTrustedServiceTokenIssuer is:

```
protected override SPTrustedAccessProvider CreateDataObject()
{
  SPSecurityTokenServiceManager localOrThrow = SPSecurityTokenServiceManager.LocalOrThrow;
  SPTrustedAccessProvider newObj = new SPTrustedAccessProvider(localOrThrow, this.Name, this.Description, this.Certificate);
  localOrThrow.TrustedAccessProviders.Add(newObj);
  return newObj;
}
```

SPSecurityTokenServiceManager.LocalOrThrow is internal but just calls Local